# How to get the Anguilla $models object in Chrome console

Tags: cme, 2013-sp1, gui-extensions

I would like to use the $models object while hacking javascript in the Google Chrome Console .

For example, I would like a 1 line sample of how to get the $models object and then be able to : `$models.getItem("tcm:1-42")`

Comment: sorry robrtc, unable to understand the question. if you execute above line directly in chrome console, it works fine.

Comment: I get this error:  ReferenceError: $models is not defined.  I want to be able to load the selected item in the GUI into an object.

Comment: $models works fine for me in Tridion 2011SP1 env and shows following Object {getOwningWindow: function, getModelFactory: function, getItem: function, createNewItem: function, getItemType: function…}

Comment: Maybe changed in 2013SP1 with the new Anguilla updates?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to ensure that you have first selected the correct frame in the console. It defaults to 'top frame' but you'll want to choose e.g. Dashboard.aspx. You'll know it's the right one when it helps you with code completion :)

[image: Correct frame selected]

Comment: Thanks Peter...the hack-ish way to get it in Chrome is window.top.frames[1].$models...

Comment: Very helpful, I was turning crazy trying to get the user in the tridion 2013 dashboard, using the js console in chrome.